# Combine git repos with same named tags such that the new repo can checkout all files from both repos

Tags: git

Lets say I have 3 git repos (project1, project2, project3).

Each of the repos have several tags in common (tag1/tag2/tag3).

I would like to combine these repos into a single git repo

```
mergedRepo
    project1
    project2
    project3
```

such that when I do a git checkout tag1 on the merged repo, I get the contents of tag1 from each of the projects.

How would I do this?

Also, would it change things drastically (if so, I'll post this as a different question) if project1 becomes a parent directory to projects 2/3 like so:

```
mergedRepo
    project1
        project2
        project3
```

-edit- Either Windows or Linux instructions are valid options (I've got a Linux VM running on a windows host).

Comment: In which kind of operating system do you want to do this, Windows or Unix?

Comment: @JonasBerlin either windows or Linux.  I've got a Linux VM running on a Win7 host.  Both have git tools installed and a shared directory for the repos.

Comment: Are all the tags on the master branch in each project? Is it ok to lose all other branches?

Comment: @JonasBerlin yes, all tags are on the master branch.  In theory, I would like to keep the other branches (there are only a few in each repository and they would also have the same names in each one) but if it makes it easier, they could be dropped.

Comment: Ok.. Going with just the master branch first. If I have time I'll figure out the other branches as well :)

Comment: Are the tags so called "lightweight" tags (see `git tag --help`) or are they "annotated" tags?

Comment: All tags are annotated

Comment: The new tags won't be annotated but the original tags will retain their annotations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124598/discussion-between-jonas-berlin-and-kinar).

Comment: As @kinar decided to take a different approach (discussion behind the link above), I'll post a link to my incomplete answer here in case somebody is interested: https://gist.github.com/xkr47/23a2eb96bad4a1743cb6d985d5942940